How can I derive ~a=b→☐~a=b in SQML?
I have been thinking about this question for a long time but didn't seem to make any progress. Here are the axioms of SQML:


Why can't you just use NEC (which isn't generally true) to draw the conclusion immediately.  If A then it's necessary that A.  So if not (X=Y) then it's necessary that not (X=Y), by NEC?  Or, is there an error in your expression of NEC, so that NEC should read it's necessary that A; therefore A?

@leepappas No you can't. NEC only sends p to ☐p but you cannot have p→☐p, since this is not generally true in SQML. I'm showing ⊢~a=b→☐~a=b, not {~a=b}⊢☐~a=b.

I don't know if this helps, but the denotation of symbols doesn't vary in time.  Thus if not (a=b) then it's necessary that not (a=B), so it IS true, but I don't see that SQML is strong enough to derive it.

I’ll provide a sketch of the proof in SQML.
1. a=b→□(a=a)→□(a=b) II

2. □(a=a)            RX, NEC

3. a=b→□(a=b)        1,2 Prop. Logic

4. □(a=b→□(a=b))     3 NEC

5. ◊(a=b)→◊□(a=b)    4, system K theorem □(P→Q)→◊P->◊Q

6. ◊(a=b)→a=b        5, S5 theorem ◊□P→P, Prop. Logic

7. ¬(a=b)→□¬(a=b)    6, Prop. Logic, def ◊


As far as I can tell, this is the simplest method to prove it. I could be wrong, but I do not believe that ¬(a=b)→□¬(a=b) is a theorem of quantified S4 or other quantified modal systems not containing the B axiom. This is because, as Bumble pointed out, line 6 follows from line 5 in quantified KB, since ◊□P→P is the contrapositive of the B axiom.

Looks fine. You don't need S5 to get ◇□P → P, you only need KTB for that. In fact in general, if you have KT and B you can derive ⊢ □(P → □P) → (¬P → □¬P) which takes you straight from step 4 to 7.

@Bumble of course, thanks for pointing that out.

@Bumble,  what are KT and B?

That is clear, thanks. By the way, the first line needs one more pair of brackets and the brackets around a=b are redundant. 5th line can be more explicit since I didn't quite get the twice contrapositive at first sight.

I’m using the common convention to bracket equalities under the scope of an operator and to drop brackets around chains of implications in a right-associative manner.

@leepappas Those are some of the axioms of modal logic. K is □(P → Q) → (□P → □Q), T is □P → P, and B is P → ◻◊P. You can get different systems of modal logic depending on which axioms you include.


How can I derive ~a=b→☐~a=b in SQML?

There's an alternative to RX and II, that allows you to prove this quickly, that I discovered recently.  It's a modal logic version of Hao Wang's axiom of Identity.
Modal Logic Version of Hao Wang's axiom of Identity
∀y[Φ(y) iff ∃x[◊x=y ∧ Φ(x)]]
In a related thread I show how to use this axiom to prove the following substitution principle.
Substitution Principle
If ◊ α= β ∧ Φ(α) then Φ(β)
Which is Semantically equivalent to
◊ α= β → (Φ(α) → Φ(β))
I then show how to derive universal generalization.
Now the first goal is to prove RX.
Theorem 1: ∀y [◊y=y]
Define ∀z[Φ(z) iff ~(◊z=β)]

Φ(β) iff ∃x[◊x=β ∧ Φ(x)]] [axiom, UI]
Φ(β) iff ~(◊β=β) [Df]
~(◊β=β) iff ∃x[◊x=β ∧ Φ(x)] [1,2; rule of replacement]
~(◊β=β) [OSC1]
∃x[◊x=β ∧ Φ(x)]] [3,4; MP2]
◊x1=β ∧ Φ(x1) [5; EI]
Φ(x1) iff ~(◊x1=β) [Df]
◊x1=β ∧ ~(◊x1=β) [6,7; RR]
~(◊β=β) → contradiction [4-8; CSC1]
◊β=β [9; RAA, DN]
∀y[◊y=y] [10; UG]

Q E.D.
Theorem 2: ∀z[z=z]
Proof found here.
Q.E.D.
Thus RX is proved.
Now let Φ(β) be ☐α=β in the substitution principle.
Theorem 3: ◊ α= β → α=β

◊ α= β → (☐α=α→ ☐α=β)
α = α [Th.2]
☐α=α [2; NEC]
◊ α= β → ☐α=β [1,3; propositional calculus]
☐α=β → α=β [T]
◊ α= β → α=β [4,5; HS]

Q.E.D.
At this point you can prove your theorem quickly.
 1. ◊ a=b → a=b             [Th.3]
 2. ~☐~a=b →  a=b           [1; Df]    
 3. ~(a=B) → ☐~a=b          [2; transposition]

Theorem 4: P → ◊P

☐~P → ~P [T]
~~P →  ~☐~P [1; transposition]
P → ◊P [3; DN, Df]

Q.E.D.
Theorem 5; ◊ α= β ↔ α=β

◊ α= β → α=β [Th.3]
α=β → ◊ α= β [Th.4]
◊ α= β ↔ α=β [1,2; conj, Df]

Q.E.D.
Theorem 5, and the rule of replacement allow you to prove II, from this system's substitution principle.
Theorem 6: α= β → (Φ(α) → Φ(β))
The proof is left to the reader.
Q.E.D.
This alternative to SQML, has one less axiom, and one less underived rule of inference.  It's simpler than SQML.

That’s not even close to an argument.
